# Monit having trouble determining if the Bitcoin daemon is running

Tags: linux, monit

I'm setting up Monit to monitor the Bitcoin daemon to make sure it runs 24/7 and restarts it if something goes wrong. The Bitcoin binary is at `/usr/local/bin/bitcoind`, and the data directory is at `/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin`.

I have told Monit to monitor the daemon through the pid file `/var/run/bitcoind.pid` every 2 minutes and start / stop the daemon as the user `bitcoin`. However, this is where I've spent countless hours trying to figure what is wrong.

Because I do not have a startup / upstart script for `bitcoind`, I have it directly pass commands to the binary itself, which can be seen with the following `/etc/monit/monitrc` file:

```
set daemon 120
set logfile /var/log/monit.log 

check process bitcoind with pidfile "/var/run/bitcoind.pid"
    start program "/usr/local/bin/bitcoind -pid=/var/run/bitcoind.pid -datadir=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin -daemon"
        as uid bitcoin and gid bitcoin
    stop program "/usr/local/bin/bitcoind stop"
        as uid bitcoin and gid bitcoin
    if failed port 8332 for 2 cycles then restart
```

When the system startups, I login as the user `bitcoin` and initiate `ps -u bitcoin`. Sure enough, the `bitcoind` appears as running under my user. However, when I get Monit to display the status through `monit status`, the response shows first as `execution failed`, then `not monitored`.

I've checked `/var/run/` while `bitcoind` is running and found that there is no such file named as `bitcoind.pid`, which leaves me to think that the `bitcoind` does not have sufficient permissions to create a `pid` file in `/var/run` while running as user `bitcoin`.

For an alternative solution, I left the pid file to created in the default location (`/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoind.pid`), but the root can not access it, which also leads to the same result.

The `/var/log/monit.log` file provides no useful information, so have the 'wrappers' I've tried.

This can all be solved by running `bitcoind` as `root`, however I am worried about security issues.

Comment: I cant get monit to work - bitcoind runs as root and monit too. All the cpu triggers and emails work but bitcoin crashed every day about 23.30 and I loose a night of mining. monit just does not do anything. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in surmising that the `bitcoin` user won't have permission to write to `/var/run`, however `root` *will* be able to read `/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoind.pid`.  I would leave the PID in the latter location, and then work some more at figuring out why monit isn't reading that second location.  My bet would be a typo in the path in the monit config.